# Storing dword into address

Tags: assembly, hex, endianness, dword

I'm in middle of teaching myself certain parts of Assembly Language, and right now, I am focusing on storing data declarations in addresses.

When it comes to storing hex, I know that if I am dealing with bytes, for instance;

```
1234
```

I can store them like this:

```
Address 0000  -  12  
Address 0001  -  24
```

Because dwords are 32 bits, I am assuming that each would take up twice as much space.

If I end up with this for dword:

```
54 00 87 D1 49 5A AF 56 32
```

Would they be stored like this:

```
Address 0000  -  54  
Address 0002  -  00
Address 0004  -  87
Address 0006  -  D1
Address 0008  -  49
Address 000A  -  5A
Address 000C  -  AF
Address 000F  -  56
Address 0011  -  32
```

?

Comment: Why there are 9 bytes in the DWORD example? Anyway, what is your question about, [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I was going to try filling the rest with 0s (unless that's not correct). And yes, if I'm using little-endian, is the procedure the same even though it's 32 bits? [This site](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/DataTypes/T77_0060_big_little_endian.htm) implies that it does, and it seems to say that no matter what I'm dealing with, the steps are the same. I guess I am looking for verification.

Comment: With little-endian when you store a multi-byte value (word, dword, etc) the rule of thumb is "low byte at low address", where "low byte" means least significant byte. I am confused by your question because in the first example the WORD 1234h is stored in BE and the second example stores bytes, which have no endianness.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Well it is really DWORD 540087D1495AAF5632h. Not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: But `540087D1495AAF5632h` is not DWORD, DWORD is 4 bytes. In hexadecimal formatting you can count length of value in bytes easily, each pair of digits is one byte, so your value is in bytes `54_00_87_D1_49_5A_AF_56_32` = 9 bytes. (that's 2x DWORD + 1 BYTE).

Comment: There are more typos/glitches in your question... `Address 0001  -  24` (`34`?) and that's Big-endian .. in little-endian it would be as bytes `34 12`. And in the other example you show addresses +2 (why?), and from `0C` you go to `0F` (12+2 = 14, not 15). If you are really interested in little endian, just fire up some decent C/C++ debugger on x86 HW, do `volatile uint32_t number = 0x12345678;` and check memory content at address `&number`.

Comment: @Frog6666: Like I told you on 'dream.in.code". ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, your values exceed a dword.

On x86, a "word" is 16 bits, because the 8086 is a 16-bit microprocessor.  In this context, it means "two bytes".  A "double word" is two words, or four bytes, and a "quad word" is four words, or eight bytes.  x86 is a "little endian" processor, so it begins writing to memory from the little end of your register.

If you do something like (in intel syntax and gcc style hex numbers):

```
#Load the lowest 8 bits of the rax register (al) with 0x54
#This is loading a BYTE (1 byte)
mov   al,0x54
#Load the lowest 16 bits of the rbx register (bx) with 0x5400
#This is loading a WORD (2 bytes)
mov   bx,0x5400
#Load the lowest 32 bits of the rcx register (ecx) with 0x540087D1
#This is loading a DWORD (4 bytes)
mov   ecx,0x540087D1
#Load the entire 64 bit register rdx with 0x540087D1495AAF56
#This is loading a QWORD (8 bytes)
mov   rdx,0x540087D1495AAF56
```

Then if you were to move these to an address held in register rsi, you would get:

```
#Put the value of al (0x54) into address at [rsi+0]
mov   [rsi],al
#Put the value of bx (0x5400) starting at the address at rsi+0, 
# such that [rsi+0] will be 0x00 and [rsi+1] will be 0x54
mov   [rsi],bx
#Put the value of ecx (0x540087D1) starting at the address of rsi+0,
# such that [rsi+0] will be 0xD1, [rsi+1] will be 0x87, 
# [rsi+3] will be 0x00, and [rsi+4] will be 0x54
mov   [rsi],ecx
#Put the value of rdx (0x540087D1495AAF56) starting at the address of rsi+0,
#such that [rsi++0] will be 0x56, [rsi+1] will be 0xAF, 
# [rsi+2] will be 0x5A, [rsi+3] will be 0x49, 
# [rsi+4] will be 0xD1, [rsi+5] will be 0x87,
# [rsi+6] will be 0x00, and [rsi+7] will be 0x54
mov   [rsi],rdx
```

Your example value, with 9 bytes, doesn't fit into any of the registers, and isn't a machine type.

So your resulting ram for a double word would look like:

0x540087D1
(little endian, such as x86):
First address-  0xD1
Second address-  0x87
Third address- 0x00
Fourth address- 0x54

(big endian, such as SPARC):
First address- 0x54
Second address- 0x00
Third address- 0x87
Fourth address- 0xD1

I will also add that in future assembly questions, you should always discuss the architecture in question- there's almost no generic assembly questions.